# Item color doesn't change on click

Tags: android, xml

i created a simple android sliding menu, the problem is that the item color doesn't change when i click on it .

here are my xml resources :

**list_item_bg_pressed.xml :**(under Drawable)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
    android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
    android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
    android:angle="90" />
 </shape>
```

**list_item_bg_normal.xml :** (under Drawable)

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
    android:startColor="@color/menubg"
    android:endColor="@color/menubg"
    android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

**list selector.xml :** (under Drawable)

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml :** (under layout)

```
<com.example.app.MainLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"

>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/menu_listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/menubg"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:divider="@color/list_divider"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"

        >
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector to be something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" />

  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" />

  <item
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" />
</selector>
```

Resuming: You'll have several states and playing around with them you can get the desired effect.